# highcharts. How to determine the coordinates of the point where the CLICK was made?

Tags: highcharts

How to determine the coordinates of the point where the CLICK was made. If the CLICK was made exactly on the line of the graphic (not on the point of the graphic).

```
chart: { 
 events: {
  click: function(event) {}
 }
},
```

Not work

Comment: Are coordinates alone accetable as an answer, or does it have to include a check for being "on the line"?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `plotOptions.series.events.click`, not `chart.events.click`. Then simply set `tooltip.snap = 1` to get clicks only when cursor is really close to the line/point. To get coordinates use `event.chartX` and `event.chartY`:

```
    tooltip: {
        snap: 1  
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            events: {
                click: function (e) {
                    console.log(e.chartX, e.chartY);
                }
            },
        }
    },
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dxj7wemh/

Comment: Fus I want to draw vertical line from the points to xAxis but I cannot get the coordinates of the point from point object. 
`      var chart = this.chart;
      H.each(this.points, function (p) {
       chart.renderer.path(['M', p.x1?, p.x2?, 'L', p.?, p.?])
            .attr({
                'stroke-width': 2,
                stroke: 'red'
            }).add();
      });`

Here is the JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LLExL/8067/

Comment: Use `point.plotX`/`point.plotY` and `yAxis.top`+`yAxis.height`. `chart.plotTop` and `chart.plotLeft` will be helpful too.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Additionally, you can keep your line under `point.something` and animate on chart update, extremes change etc: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/LLExL/8081/ One more thing: I would check if a line is rendered within the plotting area (using `yAxis.width/height/left/top`).

Comment: Fus Thank you so much for the nice tips. :)